# Can't access meteor lib helpers from client

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to understand meteorjs and have a little question.

I wanted to create a getDateTime helper and wanted this helper to be available on the client and the server.

I then inserted this code in lib/helpers

```
function getDateTime() {
    var now     = new Date();
    var year    = now.getFullYear();
    var month   = now.getMonth()+1;
    var day     = now.getDate();
    var hour    = now.getHours();
    var minute  = now.getMinutes();
    var second  = now.getSeconds();
    if(month.toString().length == 1) {
        var month = '0'+month;
    }
    if(day.toString().length == 1) {
        var day = '0'+day;
    }
    if(hour.toString().length == 1) {
        var hour = '0'+hour;
    }
    if(minute.toString().length == 1) {
        var minute = '0'+minute;
    }
    if(second.toString().length == 1) {
        var second = '0'+second;
    }
    var dateTime = year+'/'+month+'/'+day+' '+hour+':'+minute+':'+second;
    return dateTime;
}
```

Unfortunately this function is not available ( "undefined" ) on the client.

When I look at the source, I can see it but it is encapsulated in:

(function(){ };

I don't quite understand why this is for.

What should I do to access the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `.js` file in a Meteor application is enclosed in an immediately-invoked function expression `(function () { ... })()` to prevent local variables from cluttering the global scope. To make that function accessible in other files, define it like this:

```
// note: no "var"
getDateTime = function () {
  // ...
};
```